# Workflow won't compile

Tags: xaml, tfsbuild

I'm getting the following error when trying to execute my custom build definition (containing only 1 custom CodeActivity):

```
Exception Message: Expression Activity type 'CSharpReference`1' requires compilation in order to run.  Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled. (type NotSupportedException)
```

I've tried multiple suggested answers to this error, but none of them are applicable to my activity. My CodeActivity only has a couple of methods that search through directories for specific files, and then returns a delimited string containing the file names.

I don't use any WorkflowInvoker or any DynamicActivities. For what reason would I keep getting this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to work in a clean xaml file, but instead to use the Default Template provided by TFS. The Default template ran my activities without errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on an assignment step.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Expression Activity type 'CSharpValue`1' requires compilation in order to run.  
Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.
```

The resolution was to remove the carriage returns from statement.

For example this works:

```
new Foo() { Bar = new Bar() { MyProp1 = "123" } }
```

This does not:

```
new Foo() 
{ 
    Bar = new Bar()
    {
        MyProp1 = "123"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this solution as well by using the Default Template provided by TFS, clearing all of their activities, and adding the custom activities and arguments in my original custom template.

However, more insight in to this issue, it seems to be caused by the fact that custom template use C# expressions to handle the arguments. Where as the default template is set up to use VB Expressions for it's arguments.

In my case, the language didn't matter because the values were simply strings.